# best way to copy data from one aws queue (SQS) to another SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an sqs queue in the same account and region, for some new features testing I have deployed my UAT code on prod environment with different config it's a connect process where one process passes the message to other using SQS.

Now since UAT has a different SQS queue but expects the same message as we publish on the prod queue, just wanted to check if there is a config which can help me replicate the messages into a differnt queue instead of explicitly writing a code.

Answer (score 12):

**Option 1: Use Amazon SNS to fan-out to Amazon SQS queues**

If you have access to the process that sends the message to the Amazon SQS queue, then you could change it:

- Send the message to an **Amazon SNS topic**
- **Subscribe** the Amazon SQS queues to the SNS topic

This way, when a message is sent to SNS, it will be forwarded to all of the subscribed SQS queues. This avoids having to copy messages between queues.

Be sure to configure the SQS subscriptions for **Raw Message Delivery** so that they receive exactly the same message as was originally sent to SNS.

**Option 2: Duplicate messages**

If you do not have the ability to change how messages are sent and you do actually need to copy messages from one queue to another, you will need to write a program to do so. It would need to:

- Loop through the source queue by calling `ReceiveMessages()` multiple times to get each message, passing a high `VisibilityTimeout` value

  - Use `SendMessage()` to send the message to the destination queue
  - Do not delete the source message (This will cause the messages to remain invisible for a period)

The `ReceiveMessage()` call can specify a `VisibilityTimeout` period. Set this very high such that the messages won't become visible again until after all messages have been retrieved. This will prevent messages being processed more than once.

The new messages in the destination queue will not be identical to the source messages because they will have different IDs and timestamps. However, the content of the message itself will be preserved.

Comment: Thanks, John.. this isn't something that I need permanently its just matter of a month or so until we transition to the prod environment, I think writing code will only seem a viable solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the AWS CLI and the jq tool installed then a bash script along these lines should work. Although it will be slow, it's adequate for ad hoc use.

```
#!/bin/bash

#Transfers messages from one SQS queue to another

if [[ $# -ne 2 ]]
then
    echo "usage $0 : from-queue to-queue"
    exit 1
fi

echo getting
aws sqs receive-message --queue-url=$1 >m1
STATUS=$? 
if [[ -s m1 ]]
then 
    cat m1 | jq ".Messages|.[0]|.Body|fromjson" > m1.body
    rh=`cat m1 |  jq ".Messages|.[0]|.ReceiptHandle" |tr -d \"`
    echo sending
    aws sqs send-message --queue-url=$2 --message-body file://m1.body
    echo deleting
    aws sqs delete-message --queue-url=$1  --receipt-handle=$rh
else 
    echo done
fi
```